# Connecting matlab input (stdin) to java

Tags: java, matlab, redirect, stdin

I'm calling a java function from matlab. This function must get user input. I'm not sure how to connect the matlab command window (from where the user would place input) to Java. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If the java method takes a String, i.e.

```
public void inputToJava(String input)
{
    // Do Something...
}
```

Then in matlab, use the [`input`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/input.html) command to take a string from the user.

```
responseString = input('Please enter a string: ', 's');
myJavaObject.inputToJava(responseString);
```